# Would it be a good idea if compiler resolved nulls when Optional<Object> is expected as argument?

Tags: java, java-8, nullable

That would be so obviously useful that I am starting to think I am missing a rationale to avoid it, since I am sure Oracle would have made it that way. It would be the most valuable feature on Optional for me.

```
public class TestOptionals{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        test(null);
    }

    public static void test(Optional<Object> optional){
        System.out.println(optional.orElse(new DefaultObject()));
    }
}
```

(This throws a NullPointerException)

Without that feature I see too verbose using Optional for the argument.
I prefer a simple `Object optional` signature and 
checking it by `if (null = optional)` that creating the object Optional for comparing later. It is not valuable if that doesn't help you checking the null

Comment: It would probably require a lot of special cases. What about `Optional<Object> o = null;`? Do fields get default-initialized to Optional.empty? What about `Object o = null; Optional<Object> oOpt = (Optional<Object>)o;`? What about arrays of Optionals? What do you do if you really do want a null Optional reference?

Comment: But why on earth would you like to end up with a null Optional. Isn't optional precisely the OOP to treat with nulls? IMHO Optional should never be nullable as it is precisely a null checker.

Comment: Optional might be a different way to handle nulls *with your proposal*, but it isn't right now.

Comment: Why would you want a `null` optional? Well, what should `new HashMap<String, Optional<Object>>().get("hello")` return?

Comment: An optional object with isPresent = false, of course. For me Optional should be a compiler-smart null wrapper

Comment: Maybe this question asks for an opinion? In such a case, it shouldn't be posted here. Anyway, I agree that Java does not need optionals as such. Optionals were introduced with the stream api, because they are a convenient way of handling single optional items in a stream-like (fluent) way, such as `System.out.println(list.stream().filter(...).transform(...).somethingThatReturnsOptionalString(...).orElse("nothing"));`

Comment: Basically, you would like autoboxing of nullable values to Optionals. The precedent is there.

Comment: @user1352530 how would you tell between an empty optional stored in the map, versus the key not being present in the map? Using a separate call to `containsKey`? (More to the point, this change would break code that was already working, which is something they try to never ever ever do)

Comment: I don't understand, are you referring to optional keys or optional values? In case of keys I wouldn't allow Optionals. In case of values I don't see the difference semantically from null to option

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There was a **HUGE** discussion of `Optional` on all the various Java mailing lists, comprising hundreds of messages. Do a web search for

```
site:mail.openjdk.java.net optional
```

and you'll get links to lots of them. Of course, I can't even hope to summarize all the issues that were raised. There was a lot of controversy, and there was quite a breadth of opinion about *how much* "optionality" should be added to the platform. Some people thought that a library solution shouldn't be added at all; some people thought that a library solution was useless without language support; some people thought that a library solution was OK, but there was an enormous amount of quibbling about what should be in it; and so forth. See this [message from Brian Goetz](http://mail.openjdk.java.net/pipermail/lambda-dev/2012-May/004879.html) on the lambda-dev mailing list for a bit of perspective.

One pragmatic decision made by the lambda team was that any optional-like feature couldn't involve any language changes. The language and compiler team already had its hands full with lambda and default methods. These of course were the main priorities. Practically speaking, the choices were either to add `Optional` as a library class or not at all.

Certainly people were aware of other languages' type systems that support option types. This would be a big change to Java's type system. The fact is that for most of the past 20 years, reference types have been nullable, and there's been a single, untyped `null` value. Changing this is a massive undertaking. It might not even be possible to do this in a compatible way. I'm not an expert in this area, but most such discussions have tended to go off into the weeds pretty quickly.

A smaller change that might be more tractable (also mentioned by [Marko Topolnik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28663040/would-it-be-a-good-idea-if-compiler-resolved-nulls-when-optionalobject-is-expe/28663959#comment45622383_28663040)) is to consider the relationship between reference types and `Optional` as one of boxing, and then bring in the support for autoboxing/autounboxing that's already in the language.

Already this is somewhat problematic. When auto(un)boxing was added in Java 5, it made a large number of cases much nicer, but it added a lot of rough edges to the language. For example, with auto-unboxing, one can now use `<` and `>` to compare the values of boxed `Integer` objects. Unfortunately, using `==` still compares references instead of values! Boxing also made overload resolution more complicated; it's one of the most complicated areas of the language today.

Now let's consider auto(un)boxing between reference types and `Optional` types. This would let you do:

```
Optional<String> os1 = "foo";
Optional<String> os2 = null;
```

In this code, `os1` would end up as a boxed string value, and `os2` would end up as an empty Optional. So far, so good. Now the reverse:

```
String s1 = os1;
String s2 = os2;
```

Now `s1` would get the unboxed string `"foo"`, and `s2` would be unboxed to `null`, I guess. But the point of `Optional` was to make such unboxing explicit, so that programmers would be confronted with a decision about what to do with an empty `Optional` instead of having it just turn into `null`.

Hmmm, so maybe let's just do autoboxing of `Optional` but not autounboxing. Let's return to the OP's use case:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    test(null);
}

public static void test(Optional<Object> optional) {
    System.out.println(optional.orElse(new DefaultObject()));
}
```

If you *really* want to use `Optional`, you can manually box it one line:

```
public static void test(Object arg) {
    Optional<Object> optional = Optional.ofNullable(arg);
    System.out.println(optional.orElse(new DefaultObject()));
}
```

Obviously it might be nicer if you didn't have to write this, but it would take an enormous amount of language/compiler work, and compatibility risk, to save this line of code. Is it really worth it?

What seems to be going on is that this would allow the caller to pass `null` in order to have some specific meaning to the callee, such as "use the default object" instead. In small examples this seems fine, but in general, loading semantics onto `null` increasingly seems like a bad idea. So this is an additional reason not to add specific language support for boxing of `null`. The `Optional.ofNullable()` method mainly is there to bridge the gap between code that uses `null` and code that uses `Optional`.

Comment: Excellent insight thanks!! I did not think about the possibility of what you named reverse implementation, I have more doubts on that.

Comment: +1 For me the killer argument is the diminutive bulk of the boilerplate that would need several pages of JLS to eliminate, and a potential explosion in the amount of reasoning needed to get to the bottom of specific situations in code. People should go and actually *read* the [JLS section dealing with signature resolution](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2). With that in mind I have no trouble spelling out `Optional.ofNullable`.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Sure, if one of the operands is a primitive, unboxing is done. But if both are boxed, then `==` is reference equality. This means that, even if you don't care about overhead, you can't just say "I'll use boxed primitives everywhere."

Answer (score 1):

If you are committed to using the Optional class, then see the other answers.

On the other hand, I interpreted your question as, "Would it be a good idea to avoid the syntactic overhead of using Optional while still obtaining a guarantee of no null pointer exceptions in your code?"  The answer to this question is a resounding yes.  Luckily, Java has a feature, type annotations, that enables this.  It does not require use of the the Optional class.

You can obtain the same compile-time guarantees, without adding Optional to your code and while retaining backward compatibility with existing code.

1. Annotate references that might be null with the `@Nullable` type
   annotation.
2. Run a compiler plugin such as the [Checker Framework](http://checker-framework.org/)'s [Nullness Checker](http://types.cs.washington.edu/checker-framework/current/checker-framework-manual.html#nullness-checker).

If the plugin issues no errors, then you know that your code always checks for null where it needs to, and therefore your code never issues a null pointer exception exception at run time.

The plugin handles the special cases mentioned by @immibis and more, so your code is much less verbose than code using Optional.  The plugin is compatible with normal Java code and does not require use of Java 8 as Optional does.  It is in daily use at companies such as Google.

Note that this approach requires you to supply a command-line argument to the compiler to tell it to run the plugin.  Also note that this approach does not integrate with Optional; it is an alternate approach.